# How to Retrieve Data from Oracle Database using ML.NET's DatabaseSource Class

Tags: c#, oracle, ml.net

I have a Data Mart in Oracle I am trying to connect to via ML.NET's `DatabaseSource` connector. The examples in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/load-data-ml-net#load-data-from-a-relational-database) show how to connect to a SQL database like so:

```cs
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=<YOUR-DB-FILEPATH>;Database=<YOUR-DB-NAME>;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

string sqlCommand = "SELECT Size, CAST(NumBed as REAL) as NumBed, Price FROM House";

DatabaseSource dbSource = new DatabaseSource(SqlClientFactory.Instance, connectionString, sqlCommand);
```

However, connecting to Oracle doesn't appear to be as straightforward. Oracle's [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT150) indicate that I need to obtain the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` and then I need to load the DbProviderFactory with something like:

```cs
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("My Invariant Name");
DatabaseSource dbSource = new DatabaseSource(factory, connectionString, sqlCommand);
```

I tried this, but (1) after installing the Oracle Universal Installer as indicated in the docs and (2) trying to load the DbProviderFactory I am getting an error saying that "The specified invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers."

This whole approach feels unnecessarily complex when there seem to be various official Oracle NuGet packages, which would contradict the documentation I am reading (to use the Oracle Universal Installer). However I am unsure of how to use this with the ML.NET `DataBaseSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the NuGet package `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` from Oracle. My sample usage is below.

```cs
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

public static IDataView LoadDataFromDataMart(MLContext mlContext)
{
    var databaseloader = mlContext.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader<MyLoaderType>();

    string connectionString = $"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = 
        hostname_here)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = service_name_here)));User 
        ID=user_id_here;Password=password_here";

    string sqlCommand = "Select * from Table";
    DatabaseSource dbSource = new DatabaseSource(new OracleClientFactory(), connectionString, 
    sqlCommand);
    IDataView dataview = databaseloader.Load(dbSource);
    return dataview;
}
```

The answer ended up being really simple but it took me far longer to figure it out than it should have, due to some out-of-date information on the web, so I thought it worth it to post the answer here.

#### Resources

in [this Oracle Q&A](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4164107/how-to-bundle-a-provider-inside-of-my-application) and [this Oracle official doc](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html), and a little bit of experimentation.